# Aggregation function && group by

Tags: sql, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have this Sql query

```
select U.DisplayName, U.Reputation , nombre = count(B.Id) 
from Badges B, Users U
where U.Location like '%usa%'
and B.UserId = U.Id
group by B.Id
```

I don't understand why i got this error

`Column 'Users.DisplayName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

- What are the reasons of this error?
- How can i fix it?

Comment: U.displayname is not in group by list

Comment: What do u mean ??? i put `group by B.Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ the Error means that the column `'Users.DisplayName'` is not included in the Group list. Means that every column in the `SELECT`CLause must be an aggregate function or included in the Groûp by List.

The rules for forming a `GROUP BY` clause are as follows:

- The `GROUP BY` can specify any number of valid expressions, including columns of the table.
- Generally the `GROUP BY` is used to specify columns in the table that will contain common data, in order to    “group” rows together for performing some sort of aggregate function    on the set of rows.
- The only items allowed in the select list of a `SELECT` that includes a
  `GROUP BY` clause are

  - Expressions that are specified in the `GROUP BY`
  - Aggregate functions
- Expressions that are specified in the `GROUP BY` do not have to beincluded  in the SELECT statement’s select list

2/ try To include The column in the select list :

```
select U.DisplayName, U.Reputation , nombre = count(B.Id) 
from Badges B, Users U
where U.Location like '%usa%'
and B.UserId = U.Id
group by U.DisplayName, B.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select U.DisplayName, U.Reputation , nombre = count(B.Id) 
from Badges B, Users U
where U.Location like '%usa%'
and B.UserId = U.Id
group by U.DisplayName,U.Reputation
```